# Sql Query to add - Sign in the SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite, qsqlquery

Add the `-` sign to the transactions which are debit and need to display other transactions with `+` sign.

Answer (score 0):

In SQLite you can use [the builtin `printf()` function](https://www.sqlite.org/printf.html) to format pretty much everything.

The following expression expects a decimal argument and will return a string that represents it, with the sign prepended :

```
printf("%+f", my_decimal_column)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=8b8e9758d8b3b9bd5a223587667505de)** :

```
SELECT printf("%+f", 100.12345), printf("%+f", -100.12345)
```

```
printf("%+f", 100.12345) | printf("%+f", -100.12345)
:----------------------- | :------------------------
+100.123450              | -100.123450
```